# C++ dynamic array - via copying two arrays

Tags: c++

I need to resize an array and copy the values there... So I know, that I need a dynamic array, but I can't use `vector` and must use static array ..I wrote something like this:

```
string names1[0];

bool foo(const char * inFile1) {
int size = 0;
ifstream myfile(inFile1);
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    // iterate through lines
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {            
        string tmp[++size];
        for (int i=0; i!=size;i++)     
            tmp[i]=names1[i];
        names1=tmp;
        names1[size]=line;
    }
}
}
```

Nevertheless on line `names1=tmp;`  I get

```
main.cpp:42:20: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::string [(((unsigned int)(((int)(++ size)) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]’ to ‘std::string [0]’
```

...I'm new to C++ and as a javaguy, I'm really confused :-S Thanks for any advice, how to solve this..

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. The title has 'dynamic array' in it but the question says you 'must use static array'.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. So if you have an array `Type arr[N];` every attempted assignment `arr = whatever;` will cause a compilation error.

Comment: Whenever I see (or hear) the words "dynamic" and "array" in the same sentence I think `std::vector`.

Comment: @EricUrban I wrote it so, because everytime somebody asks question for a dynamic array, the answer is "Use vector" ...I just wanted to say, that I need to create another array, which is bigger then the previous one...and then add the reference to this array to the first one O_o

Comment: How would you do that in Java? You would use `new` and copy the contents of one array to the other. Do the same in C++. You cannot do this with static arrays.

Comment: it would be something like: int arr1=new int[100]; int arr2=new int[101]; copySomehowThoseArrays(arr1;arr2); arr1=arr2;                  But this isn't working here :-/

Comment: @Dworza static and dynamic arrays are inherently different things.

Comment: There's really no reason to _not_ use `std::vector` unless you're in a situation where you not having a full C++ environment. `std::vector` has been in the C++ standard for, what, since 1998? There's really no reason _not_ to use it.

Comment: Well..I can't use it, cuz it's a school project and we're not allowed to use vector...don't ask me why o_O I don't understand it either ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `names1` is an array containing zero entries (a problem in itself) and you try to assign that variable a single string. That will not work as a string array is not equal to a string.

To start with, I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of a a zero-sized array.

To continue you don't need to copy character by character into a temporary variable, just add the read string into the vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> names1;

// ...

while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    names1.push_back(line);
```

---

If you cant use `std::vector` then you have to allocate a proper array with *more* than zero entries. And if you exceed that then you have to reallocate that to increase the size of the array.

Something like:

```
size_t current_size = 1;
std::string* names1 = new std::string[current_size];

size_t line_counter = 0;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(myfile, line))
{
    if (line_counter > current_size)
    {
        std::string* new_names1 = new std::string[current_size * 2];
        std::copy(names1, names1 + current_size, new_names1);
        delete[] names1;
        names1 = new_names1;
        current_size *= 2;
    }
    else
    {
        names1[line_counter++] = line;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JesseGood Updated my answer with a _dynamic_ array solution, but if the OP really wants a _static_ array then the OP will have to figure it out him/her self.

Comment: Ty...that's what I was looking for :) I didn't mean static like object modifier, but I didn't know, how to explain, that I don't want to use vector but the array... In your solution, there is a small bug in `std:copy` function the third parameter should be `new_names1` ...But anyway - thanks a lot :)